# Proverb or expression about a talent being ignored or unnoticed

Tags: phrase-requests, proverb-requests

In one of his songs, Eminem says:

> It ain't too late to finally see what you closed-minded f**ks were too blind to see.
> Whoever finds me is gonna get a finder's fee

I'm looking for a proverb about the same situation: when people don't want to see or can't recognize talent in a person due to whatever reasons.
I always thought it could be "diamond in a dirt". Because people would consider the diamond of poor quality since it's covered/laying in the dirt. But they don't understand that a diamond is still a diamond after all.
But I found out people don't say so in USA or UK. So I need something similar to this.

My request is more about not even giving a chance to someone due to some minor reasons. Like when you tell "how in the world he could be a good piano player when he's from a poor family?"

Comment: There's "mute, inglorious Milton", but that might be too high-falutin for your purposes.

Comment: [Quote by Jonathan Swift: “There's none so blind as they that won't see.”](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/1128701-there-s-none-so-blind-as-they-that-won-t-see#:~:text=Quote%20by%20Jonathan%20Swift%3A%20%E2%80%9CThere's,that%20won't%20see.%E2%80%9D)?

Comment: As Calvin Coolidge said,"unrewarded genius is almost a proverb."

Answer (score 1):

**Diamond in the rough** is the US expression.

> something that is in poor condition but that is likely to become valuable with appropriate care or attention

Diamond in the rough refers to the uncut diamond. The diamonds you see in the store have been cut to certain proportions depending on the original stone. Prior to that, it is a rough diamond.

[Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/diamond-in-the-rough)

Answer (score 0):

The expression “unsung hero” may suggest what up you  looking for:

***[unsung](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unsung#)***:

> not noticed or praised for hard work, courage, or great achievements:
>
> - an unsung hero/heroine

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: thanks for reply. But unfortunately it's not what I mean. My request is more about not even giving a chance to someone due to some minor reasons. Like when you tell "how in the world he could be a good piano player when he's from a poor family?"

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is

> You can't judge a book by its cover.

From [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Never-Judge-A-Book-by-Its-Cover-meaning)

> you shouldn't judge someone or something based only on what you see on the outside or only on what you perceive without knowing the full situation. It means that the outward appearance of something is not an indication of its value or worth.

There's also

> jumping to conclusions

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jump-to-conclusions)

> to guess the facts about a situation without having enough information

Answer (score 0):

> not seeing / can't see the forest for the tree

This popular idiom was first documented in The Proverbes of John Heywood‎, 1546:

> 13 You cannot see the wood for trees.
>
> Continued proverbial, being found in an anti-popish tract of the reign of Charles II.
>
> From him who sees no wood for trees
> And yet is busie as the bees
> From him that's settled on his lees
> And speaketh not without his fees,
> Libera nos.

Libera nos: (Latin) Free us.

This idiom describes the failing or inability to notice details (or a tendency to overlook important details) due to being overly focused on "the big picture". It can be applied to situations where one person fails to notice qualities of another, especially if the failure is due to some unrelated overwhelming impression.

Example: The Director had had several run-ins with Joshua, which had left a tendency for disdain. In relegating Joshua to the role of stage hand, however, the Director failed to see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve heard people say “undiscovered genius” or “he’s a hidden talent “ or “he has a hidden talent “
Also “a wasted talent “ usually for someone who squanders their talents but could also be when circumstances cause someone to not use their gifts.